# How to change DFS to Topological Sort

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, topological-sort

I've read about the topological sort on my own but I'm not able to convert DFS pseudocode into TS

[Can anyone explain to me that how can I change this DFS to perform Topological Sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m6Wf.png)

[Can anyone tell me that what is the Pre and Post time for this graph by using DFS
Assume start vertice is 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNTwK.png)

Comment: The Pre and Post time I've calculated are the : 
Vertice 10: Pre = 1 and Post = 2
Vertice 5: Pre = 3 and Post = 10
Vertice 11: Pre = 4 and Post = 9
Vertice 2: Pre = 5 and Post = 8
Vertice 9: Pre = 6 and Post = 7
Vertice 7: Pre = 11 and Post = 14
Vertice 8: Pre = 12 and Post = 13
Vertice 3: Pre = 15 and Post = 16

Topological Sorting Order: 3,7,8,5,11,2,9,10 (Reversing the Post time)

Answer (score 0):

look at the variable time=0 on line 4, that's your variable to keep track of pre/post numbers.
line 10 assigns the value of `time` to the node that's being `visited` - `u.f`
Now, all nodes have an attribute `f` with appropriate time values. Those are post order numbers.
You need to order the nodes in descending order of those numbers. That's your topological sort.

Comment: Topological Sorting Order: 3,7,8,5,11,2,9,10 (Reversing the Post time)
It’s my order and in the first comment I’ve written the pre/post time time as well. Would you like to confirm my answers?